# visual studio: How to ignore pdb not loaded warnings during debug?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

While debugging, I do not want visual studio to be looking for *.pdb files from 3rd party *.dlls. For example I use Jetbrains Resharper TaskRunner for unit testing. To use it requires a reference to Jetbrains.Resharper.TaskRunnerFramework.dll. When I debug my application via the TaskRunner, I end up with something similar to this picture below:

[image]

Well, I'm not debugging the task runner. That isn't my code anyhow. I want Visual Studio to be "smart" enough (or have a setting) to automatically know to NOT concern itself with *.pdb files for anything that isn't my code. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you show some more context in which window this warning shows as are you using resharper?

Comment: Where do you see this warning?

Comment: is it not a visual studio setting? something like enable just my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [Just My Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457346.aspx) setting in Visual Studio. From the documentation, there's a section that sounds relevant, which discusses one of the effects of having this setting applied:

> When you Step Into (Keyboard shortcut: F11) non-user code, the debugger steps over the code to the next user statement. When you Step Out (Keyboard: Shift + F11), the debugger runs to the next line of user code. If no user code is encountered then execution continues until the app exits, a breakpoint is hit, or an exception occurs.

You can enable Just My Code in the Visual Studio options under Debugging > General:

[image]

Comment: This worked. I'd like to add for anyone reading this answer that I also had to add-back the exception catches that I had set to not stop at during debugging. Look in the debugger assistant to add them back.

Answer (score -4):

Add a .gitignore file to your solution and add all extensions you want to ignore
Add this in your .gitignore file *.pdb

Comment: I'm not using git.